# How can I disable __vwd/js/artery in VS.NET 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I've upgraded to VS.NET 2013, and now, every time I start to debug an ASP.NET MVC4 app in IIS, some how  __vwd/js/artery is created, this script is interfering with my RequireJS setup and it crashes the jQuery reference.

Does anyone know how can i get rid of this script?

__vwd/js/artery

```
window.vwdTempJQuery = window.jQuery = window.$;
window.jQuery = window.$ = null;
window.vwdTempJSON = window.JSON;

*! jQuery v1.8.2 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */

.....

// Restore original jQuery references.
window.jQuery = window.$ = window.vwdTempJQuery;
window.vwdTempJQuery = null;
// Restore original JSON.
if (window.JSON !== window.vwdTempJSON)
    window.JSON = window.vwdTempJSON;

....
```

### LE: It has been fixed in Visual Studio 2013 RTM

Comment: it doesn't seem to be fixed. I'm still getting errors on the console (even tho it doesn't seem to cause much trouubles). My version of VS2013 is: 12.0.21005.1 REL

Comment: @Geeo are you getting errors when loading jQuery with RequireJS?

Comment: I'm not using RequireJS but when "Browser Link" is active I get errors in the console.

Comment: Took me forever to find this answer - Mainly because I didn't know what to ask that wasnt vague..

Answer (score 316, accepted):

A friend of mine found it, it's `Enable Browser Link` 
[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue  this fixed it for me too but this feature is one of the main reasons I'm even trying this preview and would really like to see this fixed soon. I filed a bug using your question here (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/793612/vs-2013-browser-link-generated-script-causes-jquery-reference-to-be-broken-when-using-requirejs)

Comment: Thank you for this, turning it off also helped to get rid of problem with empty WebResources.axd files under vs2013 in chrome.

Comment: Would it be possible to send us a sample app that reproduces the issue with RequireJS? We would like to address this in the upcoming release. Please send the details to **reshmim** at Microsoft.com. Thank you for your feedback! -Reshmi Mangalore

Comment: @reshmimangalore please test on this project https://github.com/stefanprodan/RequireJSDotNet

Comment: @Vlad it causes issues with RequireJS or you have a different setup?

Comment: @StefanP. Different setup - a brownfield project with jQuery and some MicrosoftAjax. No RequireJs. Enabling Browser Link messes up the tabbed interface we have.

Comment: these toolbars are non-existant in VS 2013 Professional edition - how do I turn off this crap?

Comment: For those of you that have your toolbars disabled (like I do), you can find this under the "Standard" toolbar.

Comment: @MrDustpan, I would like to add this "Browserlink" button to another toolbar.  Where is it in "Add Command"?

Comment: So _that_ was the cause of my Visual Studio Professional 2013 (Update 4) eating up my CPU cycles, as well as my browser (Chrome). Could hardly get any work done because of this - wrongly blaming my poor extensions. Good bye Browser link! *unchecking feature by pressing hard on mouse button* ngh!

Comment: Awesome this work for me as well.  Hard to Web Debug with 100's to 1000's of the arterySignalR requests.

Comment: If after turning it off `Stephan P's` way and it is still polling, a probable cause is that you need to also turn it off in the other instances of Visual Studio you have running.

Comment: Interestingly, when I had the Default Host Application set to Google Chrome (as pictured in this answer), hitting the "live" URL with Firefox caused the Browser Link to come back, even though I'd turned it off. (I have Firefox tuned to use a < 100% zoom when I don't have an external monitor.) Changed the Default Host Application to Firefox, and it's happy, strangely enough.

Answer (score 56):

I found that it was still running until I actually added a value for it in the Web.config appSettings to turn it off.

```
<add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
```

Comment: This would be good if you want to turn it off per-site, not globally like the answer by @StefanP