# .net localhost website consistently making get arterySignalR/poll?transport=longPolling&connectionToken= calls

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I created a new VS 2013 project and viewed the default.aspx page with the Firefox browser. When I check the net calls it has made, I see it making constant calls to:

```
http://localhost:50682/6a663a78019845d5ade4a328cad09cc2/arterySignalR/poll?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAOBmDwPWa2ky2MAZXFHBMVAAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAADSADQXBVKiKczflJ0OzUjOLduFTJE4zd%2FLHWGpDfXnuAAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAACyEX81VwilygfphPoEKCYQ6ZwrkzExoKfZzEMkqBKqqzAAAADG%2BDJbrEFOfsNm9OKhqacnGseQvrwy5kmyZnI5YJiZbjYFgzMELXHfwA7Sxjj4osJAAAAAvQvoG4N0nn8eB9FRaJaZyqaUDF%2F9ypvGN%2B%2BVefnx8U1Fq6P9HXO9vEC%2BfA2s8R4jik58rD4IcFMjM4P8l5kv6g%3D%3D&messageId=d-F1180A0E-W%2C0%7Cl%2C4%7Cm%2C0&requestUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A50656%2Fdefaulttest&browserName=Firefox&tid=4&_=1384207744328
```

Why is it doing that? 
How do I stop those calls?
I see an infinite number of calls made to the above URL every 6 seconds. 
Please help me understand this and fix this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390158/how-can-i-disable-vwd-js-artery-in-vs-net-2013

Comment: Thank you Gustavo. This stopped the connections. Thanks again.

Comment: Of course it isn't making an infinite number of calls. :)

Answer (score 305):

This is working as intended.  Artery aka BrowserLink is a real-time connection from Visual Studio to all browsers running your code.  It essentially allows Visual Studio to interact with every browser.

For instance if you have IE, Opera, Chrome and Firefox all running your code and you're trying to ensure cross browser correctness; instead of going to each browser and hitting f5 to refresh you can just click the browser link refresh button which will auto-refresh all of the pages for you.

Not everyone wants or needs to have this functionality so if you do want to disable it, as Gustavo Armenta said you can disable it by following the steps here: [How can I disable __vwd/js/artery in VS.NET 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390158/how-can-i-disable-vwd-js-artery-in-vs-net-2013)

Comment: Here is a link which describes it in detail and how to use it ["How to use Browser Link"](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link)

Comment: This "tool" basically broke my javascript code today. It prevents chrome from showing the print preview page until page reloads.

Comment: Following VS2013 Update 4 this feature seems to have been consistently hanging IE11 in Windows 8...I had to disable it in order to test my website in IE11.

Comment: It makes 20K requests in less than 30 seconds and uses cpu heavily. The feature might be useful but it causes too much trouble even on an intel i7 cpu

Answer (score 119):

I would recommend you to read this post first [Browser Link feature in Visual Studio Preview 2013](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013/) to understand about this new feature that comes in with VS 2013.

And then to disable this, simply uncheck the "Enable browser link" option.

[image]

Answer (score 37):

You can hide the polling requests from the Chrome developer tools Network tab so that the requests you are actually interested in become visible. You can hide the polling requests by adding a negative filter:

- On the Network tab, click the filter button to open the filter options
- Enter "-poll" without the quotes to hide the polling requests.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Not an answer to the OP question but so useful I'll +1 it =)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore - it used to, for me, but about a month or two? ago it stopped working.

Comment: It seems that Chrome dev tools has a bug on the negative filter that was introduced this year. It should be fixed in a future stable release. Discussion over here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/cdJCK5tVqW8

Answer (score 2):

Had issues with that on site running with KnockoutJS framework. Pages were freezing for 10 seconds until "BrowserLink" external scripts were loading (using Chrome browser).

Issue solved by disabling "Browser link" feature in VS 2013

Steps [How to disable "Browser link"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390158/how-can-i-disable-vwd-js-artery-in-vs-net-2013) (thanks to Gustavo Armenta for leaving comment with link in question)