# Windows 7 WPF Webbrowser and Signalr

Tags: wpf, signalr, webbrowser-control

Ok so i am currently working on a prototype that is evaluating multiple embedded browsers that will be hosted in a WPF application.  I have currently tried Awesonium, CEFSharp, and the native WebBrowser control for WPF.  I am also currently using Signalr for communication purposes between the server, web page, and WPF application. During my testing i noticed that Awesonium and CEFSharp will send a message through signalr to the Hub rather quickly(sub second for sure).

When i run the native WPF WebBrowser control there is at least a 3 to 4 second lag before the message reaches the Hub. I am currently using windows 7 and i have IE 11 installed.

My co-worker is using windows 8 and does not have the lag when he runs the application. We have set the meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

We have also tried the Registry hack provided by: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version

I have the client set to use long-polling transport for consistency. And the same page is being loaded for all browsers.

here is a snippet of the javascript:

```
   var chat = $.connection.testHub;
   $.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'longPolling' }).done(function () {
       alert("Connected, transport = " + $.connection.hub.transport.name);
        $('#AweMessage').click(function () {
            alert("clicked");
            chat.server.send('awesonium').done(function () {alert('done');});
        });
        $('#NativeMessage').click(function () {
            alert("clicked");
            chat.server.send('native').done(function () { alert('done'); });
        });
        $('#CEFmessage').click(function () {
            alert("clicked");
            chat.server.send('cef').done(function () { alert('done'); });
        });
    });
```

I am at a loss here.  If anyone has any ideas I'm open to anything.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually had nothing to do with my code.

Using fiddler i was able to see that Visual Studio had its own signalr connection to each of the web pages that I was debugging.  Specifically long polling to a url that contained "arterySignaLR"  after a quick search on stackoverflow i found this post:

[.net localhost website consistently making get arterySignalR/poll?transport=longPolling&connectionToken= calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917595/net-localhost-website-consistantly-making-get-arterysignalr-polltransport-long)

once i turned off the BrowserLink, my connections were freed up and my web application was no longer slow.

I was eventually able to reproduce this on my co-worker's Windows 8 machine, although he did not experience it as quickly because, Windows 8 will use WebSockets as its primary transportation mode, and to my knowledge there are no limitations for concurrent websocket connections.  On the other hand, my windows 7 PC was using long polling for everything and chewing up my connection limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the hub code using IE debugger.

http://blogs.perl.org/users/mark_leighton_fisher/2011/09/debugging-javascript-in-a-webbrowser-control-from-vs2010.html

Find out exactly what takes that much time. You ca step through the code and find out what line takes so much time - it might not even be the actual sending, but something other.

Secondly, you might be able to use `ApiMonitor` once you track down which call is blocking - and see what is going on.

Oher than that:

- try different transport systems
- see if it happens with other user on same machine