# Disable Browser Link - which toolbar

Tags: visual-studio, browser-link

I want to disable visual studios browser link. I found this question:
[How can I disable __vwd/js/artery in VS.NET 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390158/how-can-i-disable-vwd-js-artery-in-vs-net-2013)
and many other resources saying I should untick "Enable Browser Link" in the toolbar, but that toolbar doesn't show up in my visual studio.  I've enabled all the debug toolbars but still no browser link button.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx

This should explain how to turn off browser link. You could do it via web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false"></add>
</appSettings>
```

or do it from the toolbar:

[image: What Browser Link looks like in the Toolbar]

If that button isn't available, go to VIEW > Toolbars > Standard and make sure it's checked.  Keep in mind it's only available in VS2013 and later.

Comment: Pretty annoying that the Browser Link Dashboard (the only relevant thing that Quick Launch can find) doesn't have any way to disable it! I guess it's expected that nobody turns off the Standard toolbar... but I do.

Comment: BrowserLink just flooded Chrome developer tools network section with tons of XHR requests .. ugh, disabled now, worked for VS 2015 !!

Comment: Thanks. This feature, until disabled, for me made vs2015 painfully slow. Was using VMWare Fusion, 4-8 cores on MBP, and Firefox -- not sure if IE would have been faster.

Comment: I would like to add the "Browser Link" button to a toolbar I actually use, but I can't find it in the commands to add list.

Comment: @Myster You're right I can't find it listed in the command list, strange.  Maybe someone else knows?

Comment: This really helped me a lot, browser link was hanging my chrome browser, even though i have a core i7 system.

Comment: @mik-t To answer your comment on why BrowserLink generates XHR warnings in Chrome, it's because it's using an older version of jQuery, v1.8.2, that uses the Synchronous XHRs, which is already deprecated. Disabling BrowserLink and updating/installing a new jQuery v3.1.1 (latest stable) fixes the issue.

Comment: the XML should be <appSettings>. Captal S.

Comment: I had Tools/Options set accordingly and EnableBrowserLink disabled in config but still got this during startup: assembly named 'Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Tracing' was loaded from '../Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Tracing.DLL' using the LoadFrom context....

Answer (score 61):

**My refresh button was to the right in VS 2015 in case this helps anyone:**

[image: shows refresh button for enable browser link in vs 2015]

Comment: Link no longer valid.

Answer (score 10):

Go to web.config and just type

```
<appSettings>
      <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false"/>
</appSettings>
```

Finished! Ez and simple!

Answer (score 10):

Merely unchecking `Enable Browser Link` didn't do the trick for me in VS 2017.

I had to also uncheck `Enable JavaScript debugging in ASP.NET` in `Tools > Options > Debugging` as suggested [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/14135/view.html).

Update for 15.7.4: Not related to Browser Link specifically but I had to uncheck `Stop debugger when browser window is closed` in `Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Projects` to prevent new browser windows (not tabs) from being opened when starting a project with debugging.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like it can be difficult to identify where Browser Link button is. Show Browser Link button in the toolbar:

[image]

Comment: Yes, the 'Add or remove Buttons' actually shows the 'Browser link' button, unlike 'Customize toolbars'.