# onbeforeunload doesn't work from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, onbeforeunload, browser-link

Create a web project in Visual Studio 2013, remove all scripts (which could interfere) and add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> <!-- Note that the version might be different -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload', function (e) {
        var message = "Why are you leaving?";
        e.returnValue = message;
        return message;
    });
</script>
```

The `onbeforeunload` event won't fire. However if you open this with Visual Studio 2012 it will work (note that to open it with Visual Studio 2012 you shouldn't use `ASP.NET MVC 5`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Browser Link (one of the new features of Visual Studio 2013)](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/top-things-web-developers-should-know-about-the-visual-studio-2013-release) is replacing the original `onbeforeunload` event. [Here this is reported for Firefox](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/817138/browser-link-script-breaks-onbeforeunload-event-in-firefox) although this also happens in other browsers.

If you want to work with `onbeforeunload` event you should [disable Browser Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23140874/310276).