# MVC4 c# website in localhost used heavy processor in chrome browser after loading complete

Tags: c#, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4

When i load the mvc4 website using chrome browser in localhost it start occupying the processes. I'm facing this problem only in chrome browser i have tested on other browsers like **firefox, IE** etc in this im not facing this problem.

After loading it show the usage of processor 56% and if i opened the website for few minute more it start occupying more and more processor. I test this in other pc also i get the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. This thing happened due to **Visual Studio 2013 Browser Link Feature**. Browser Link used is create the SignalR connection between Visual Studio and the browser.

For more detail check below link :

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx

So after disabling this features chrome stop eating the processes. To know how to disable this features please follow below link of Stackoverflow question:

> [Disable Browser Link - which toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101265/disable-broswer-link-which-toolbar)